# Guna framework VScrollBar in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, frameworks, scrollbar

I'm trying to design a VScrollBar in C# using Guna framework. The panel has 10 Labels on it. I used this code but It doesn't work for me

```cs
    vScrollHelper = new Guna.UI.Lib.ScrollBar.PanelScrollHelper(panel2, gunaVScrollBar1, true);
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.AutoSize = true;
        lbl.Text = "Label " + i.ToString() + " ================================================================";
        lbl.Location = new Point(6, i * lbl.Height);
        panel2.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }

    vScrollHelper.UpdateScrollBar();
    
}

private void Panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (vScrollHelper != null) vScrollHelper.UpdateScrollBar();
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like the code snippet is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 labels, consider a loop with 10 iterations:

```cs
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // Code to add labels here...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll does not have to be inside the parent of the object, you have to put it outside the panel, but without moving position, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and take it out of the parent object